# \raggedright removes paragraph indentation

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, ragged2e

This code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \raggedright

    \lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

produces three paragraphs with a ragged right edge and no paragraph indentation. Why? And how can I get a ragged right edge *with* paragraph indentation?

Also -- please feel free to add tags to this post; I didn't quite know what would be best.

Comment: I've added the tags 'indentation' and 'ragged2e'.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The definition of `\raggedright` in the LaTeX kernel is

```
% latex.ltx, line 3974:
\def\raggedright{%
  \let\\\@centercr\@rightskip\@flushglue \rightskip\@rightskip
  \leftskip\z@skip
  \parindent\z@}
```

Thus you can say in your document preamble

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\iraggedright{%
  \let\\\@centercr\@rightskip\@flushglue \rightskip\@rightskip
  \leftskip\z@skip}
\makeatother
```

removing the last instruction. Now `\iraggedright` will do what you want.

A different approach is to use `ragged2e`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{\parindent}

\begin{document}
\RaggedRight

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\RaggedRight` is less strict than `\raggedright` in that it allows hyphenation, so making “less ragged” output.

Answer (score 21):

It is common practice to typeset flush-left (aka ragged-right) paragraphs *without* indentation of the first lines of paragraphs. To compensate for this, one usually also inserts a bit of extra whitespace *between* paragraphs. You could get this effect (i.e., the extra spacing between paragraphs) by loading the `parskip` package.

To restore indentation of the first line of a paragraph, you could issue the command

```
\setlength\parindent{2em} % or whatever length you desire
```

after issuing the command `\raggedright`.

---

If you really need to typeset entire paragraphs in ragged-right mode, you should consider loading the [ragged2e](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package and issuing the command `\RaggedRight` (notice the capitalization of the two `R`s), either in the preamble or at the start of the material you want to get typeset ragged-right (flush-left). Doing so will (re)enable hyphenation, making the right-hand edges of paragraphs look much less ragged looking (pun intended) than if you used `\raggedright`. As @MartinSchröder -- the author of the `ragged2e` package -- has pointed out in a comment, the package provides the parameter `\RaggedRightParindent`. You could set this parameter equal to the basic `\parindent` parameter to re-enable indentation of the first line of every paragraph. Importantly, you should set the value of this length parameter *before* issuing the command `\RaggedRight`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlength\RaggedRightParindent{\parindent} % default value of this parameter is `0pt`
\RaggedRight % if invoked in preamble, entire document is set Ragged-Right
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ehm. `ragged2e` offers `\RaggedRightParindent`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder - Thanks for this; I've revised the final paragraph of my answer to mention this parameter and how it might/should be modified to re-enable indentation of the first line of paragraphs.