# Long word wont go to next line

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I'm using `polyglossia` package in my document and have some parts where I don't want to have `hyphynation` so I'm using `\disablehyphenation` command as documented. Now when I'm having very long words in a line I would expect the second long word to go to the next line (see section 1 in the image below). But when the first word gets shorter the second one does no longer go to the second line.

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
    \fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont
    \disablehyphenation
    \section{expected}
    Aquickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog Aquickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog
    \section{unexpected}
    Aquickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazy Aquickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog
\end{document}
```

Any ideas how to force the second word to be on the next line? (manual Newline is no option - its generated content)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Desperate times, desperate measures.. Use `\sloppy`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
    \fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont
    \disablehyphenation
    \sloppy
    \section{expected}
    Aquickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog Aquickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog
    \section{unexpected}
    Aquickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazy Aquickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want this effect locally, use `sloppypar` environment like

```
\begin{sloppypar}
content
\end{sloppypar}
```

On the other hand, you can also use `\raggedright` (thanks to R. Schumacher for reminding).

Comment: You beat me to the "sloppy" answer by about five seconds. :-)

Comment: @Mico Hehe, it happens very rarely :-)

Comment: You could also use raggedright or related options in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185970/raggedright-removes-paragraph-indentation

Comment: @R.Schumacher: I was about to add it. Thanks for the reminder. :-)

Comment: `\sloppy` will persist through the entire document unless delimited.  usually, it's better to use `\begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}` around just the affected region.  (been recommended before: [How to avoid using \sloppy document-wide to fix overfull \hbox problems?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59133/579))

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks, I have added a note.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried your suggested solution but encountered another case where the second word still wont go to second line. It happens when the first word is very short, e.g. `"Really ReallyLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongWord"`