# White spaces in URL

Tags: bibtex, urls

I am having a white space in URL. I am using BibTeX for references. In the beginning, I had two URLs (number 3 and 5, see image below) with white spaces. After searching, I came across the suggestion that I should use `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` and load it before the `hyperref` package. This did indeed work. For one URL, number 3. For the other one though (number 5), although the white space has been reduced, it still remains. I have tried so many options suggested here in several posts but so far no success. This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}          
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2.0cm, left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm, bottom=2.0cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}           
\usepackage{booktabs}                 
\usepackage{cite}                     
\usepackage{hyperref}                 
\usepackage{subfigure}              
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\intextsep}{2mm plus2mm minus2mm}



\begin{document}
...
```

Then I am just citing the URL as `\cite{...}`. Nothing special. This is the result:[image]

Here is the Bibtex:

```
@Misc{ELGA_guidelines,
  author = {{ELGA GmbH}},
  url    = {https://www.elga.gv.at/technischer-hintergrund/technische-elga-leitfaeden},
}
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid we can't compile your code to reproduce the problem because we don't know what the `...` stands for and we don't have sample `.bib` entries. Please provide a complete minimal document we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the issue, eliminating any irrelevant packages from your preamble in the process. Note that, with few exceptions, `hyperref` should be loaded last. Off-topic: `subfigure` is obsolete and ought not be used.

Comment: Sorry, added the Bibtex now. The ... is just a place holder for the Bibtex key. `/cite{BibtexKey}` in this case `/cite{ELGA_guidelines}`

Comment: Adding hyphenation points, e.g. (I don't know if they are correct in German) @Misc{ELGA_guidelines,
  author = {{ELGA GmbH}},
  url    = {https://www.elga.gv.at/technischer-hintergrund/technische-elga-leit\-fae\-den},
} may help.

Comment: That didn't help and only made the url look funny and added words like discretionary (no idea where they come from) into the url.

Comment: @cfr I am also aware of the fact that subfigure is deprecated, replaced by subfig and the new one subcaption is even recommended. Unfortunately, the subcaption package is not compatible with the class I amusing (I tried it) and what is more, the subfigure works for me for now and I really am not that bothered to fix what is not broken atm. Also, I don't think (well, at least I am not aware of it) that it is like a software version that if you don't update, there maybe security risk etc. So, I can live with it for now I guess.

Comment: Please add additional code into your question so that people do not have to try to patch something together in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Output from my attempt to turn your code into a proper minimal example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NBqfw.png). No problems at all here. Obviously, I first had to track down the non-standard class you're using and install it. I had to guess your bibliography style and complete the document environment, patching together bits from your comments with bits from your question. But I still can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: But the image you posted showed only one reference. That one is also fine for me. The problem is the one with the url https://www.elga.gv.at/technischer-hintergrund/technische-elga-leitfaeden/. Sorry I also forgot to add my bibliography style. This how it is in my code:
`\bibliographystyle{splncs03}
\bibliography{literatur}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to simply add a `\raggedright`, or `\sloppy` to the text, inside the group.

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185970/raggedright-removes-paragraph-indentation). It did indeed solve my problem. However, it increased my bad boxes from 7 to 37. I checked through my document and couldn't, at least by the look of human eyes, see any undesired side effects as a result. So, I will consider it solved. This is what fixed my problem:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlength\RaggedRightParindent{\parindent} % default value of this parameter is `0pt`
\RaggedRight
```

Comment: I would add the `\RaggedRight` instruction only at the start of the bibliography.